# What's the difference between ConstraintValidator (jpa) and Validator (Spring)?

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

According to what I know, I can perform the same type of validation with both `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator`.

Why should I prefer one validator over another?

Thank you?

Comment: their respective javadocs kind of explain this...

Comment: and the fact that ConstraintValidator is nothing to do with JPA, and everything to do with the Bean Validation API